# Dropdown select table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails project I got a dropdown, in this dropdown I wanna select specific user and see the items in a table.

Dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user users">
   <% @list.each do |i| %>
   <li>id <%= i.id%></a>
      <% end %>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <% @list[id].each do |u| %>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <ul class="list green">
               <li><%=u.id%></li>
            </ul>
         </td>
         <td><%=u.name%></td>
         <td><%=u.name%></td>
         <td><%=u.age%></td>
      </tr>
      <%end%>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How I can pass this id `<li>id <%= i.id%></a>` to here ? `<% @list[id].each do |u| %>`

Answer (score 0):

You could add the id to each list item as follows:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user users">
  <% @list.each do |i| %>
  <li data-id="#{<%= i.id%>}">
    id <%= i.id%>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Then also add the id to each row in the table and use javascript to hide all rows but the one that has an id that matches the selected id:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <% @list.each do |i| %>
        <% i.each do |u| %>
        <tr data-id="#{<%= u.id%>}">
           <td>
              <ul class="list green">
                 <li><%=u.id%></li>
              </ul>
           </td>
           <td><%=u.name%></td>
           <td><%=u.name%></td>
           <td><%=u.age%></td>
        </tr>
        <%end%>
      <%end%>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you could just use ajax to update the table.. either way would work.

Comment: no. dropdown and table are in the same page @TinMonkey